Artifactory-oss 7.98.8 "Unsupported operation: federated"
I have deployed with docker compose the OSS 7.98.8 version of Artifactory (using the image releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:7.98.8) along a postgres database (using the image releases-docker.jfrog.io/postgres:15.6-alpine). Although it works correctly, it generates the following error logs:
2024-11-18T08:12:41.671Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [69fa9639cca25a7c] [c.e.m.GlobalExceptionMapper:51] [http-nio-8081-exec-9] - Unsupported operation: federated
2024-11-18T08:12:42.492Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [4fbe3735be29c337] [c.e.m.GlobalExceptionMapper:51] [http-nio-8081-exec-6] - Unsupported operation: federated
2024-11-18T08:12:42.514Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [405d7bd780d4a705] [c.e.m.GlobalExceptionMapper:51] [ttp-nio-8081-exec-10] - Unsupported operation: federated
2024-11-18T08:12:43.010Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [1c8ec29a5de72fc4] [c.e.m.GlobalExceptionMapper:51] [http-nio-8081-exec-1] - Unsupported operation: federated
2024-11-18T08:12:43.099Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [714928c950a71f67] [c.e.m.GlobalExceptionMapper:51] [http-nio-8081-exec-8] - Unsupported operation: federated
2024-11-18T08:12:43.629Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [792b22cb37d05f13] [c.e.m.GlobalExceptionMapper:51] [http-nio-8081-exec-4] - Unsupported operation: federated

As far as I know, the “featured” is a premium feature of the Artifactory, so I don't understand why I get something that refers to it if I'm using the OSS version.
It is an error that I would not say does not affect the proper functioning of the Artifactory, but it is really annoying because those logs are generated randomly and whenever I refresh the web page.
Any help is appreciated.

If you don't work for a braindamaged employee, use artipie. That is a free artifactory. If you do, then: artifactory is a microservice thing, i.e. it runs in about 6 demons, these talk with each other on http. Try to track their communication each other. If the site works well, I think this logging nuance can be tolerated.

A similar question was posted on SO a bit earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79192477 According to the comments, this is probably an Artifactory bug that will be fixed in an upcoming release.
